# How to create a rolling period-over-period comparison in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following query that pulls all records from a Redshift table from January 1st of the current year through the final date of the most recent, full quarter.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_value BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('year',getdate()) AND DATE_TRUNC('quarter',dateadd(day,-1,getdate()));
```

I now want to create a period-over-period comparison query that returns all records for the previous *n* months. Ex. if the first query returns all records for Jan - Jun 2022, this query will return all records for Jul - Dec 2021.

Here is what I have so far, however it currently returns Jan - Jun 2021 instead of the desired date range. I've tried playing around with DATEDIFF() instead of DATEADD() but haven't had any luck with that either. Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE date_value BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('year',dateadd(year,-1,getdate())) AND DATE_TRUNC('quarter',dateadd(year,-1,getdate()));
```